# Recursive children with Laravel Commentable / Nested Set

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get all the recursive children using [Laravel Commentable](https://github.com/faustbrian/Laravel-Commentable). As of now, I can get the first children like this:

```
$user->comments()->with(['creator', 'children.creator'])->where('parent_id', null)->get()
```

But this isn't "recursive" and I'd have to do it over and over: `children.children.children` etc. How do I get all comments and their respective children so I can return it as JSON?

Example Output:

```
{
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "body": "foo",
      "children:" 
        {
          "id": 5,
          "body": "foo",
          "children:"
            {
              "id": 5,
              "body": "foo",
              // etc
            }
        }         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up retrieving all comments `$user->comments` and then sorting/arranging them like this:

```
public static function arrange($comments)
{
    $comments->transform(function ($comment) use ($comments) {
        $comment->children = $comments->where('parent_id', $comment->id);
        return $comment;
    });

   return $comments->reject(function ($comment) {
        return $comment->parent_id !== null;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try a recursive approach since you will not be certain how many children the comments will have. Just add a different method:

```
public function commentRecourse($model, $child = null){
    if(isset($model->child->id)){
        return $child . '.child';
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

This would return a new relationship string like 'children.children.children' anytime the child has a relationship. You can call this in a loop that stops when this function returns false. Like:

```
loop stuff(){
  $variable[] = commentRecourse($model, $child)
}
```

Then you pass the variable as the with() argument.

```
$user->comments()->with($variable)->where.... etc.
```

Sorry, forgot to add that json_encoding() the array'd output will show the relationships unless you've messed with the $hidden model property.